# replacing text in a div on google map marker click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a custom Google map displaying with markers on it. I have a click event firing OK, I would like to replace some text in a `<div>` to the side of the map. I can see in firebug, that the object title contains the information I would like.  I am selecting the required `<div>` OK but the text isn't showing??

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'click', function() {
  marker.info.open(map, myMarker);

   $('#text').text($(this).title); //I thought this would work??

});
```

Comment: I give you an answer based in information you put here, but I could help more if you show your html please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`google.maps.Marker.getTitle`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) method in order to get in a more directly way the information you want.

And for put some `html` (even a text like yours) in a div seems  `$(selector).html` method fits better.

Try this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'click', function () {
    marker.info.open(map, myMarker);
    $('#text').html(this.getTitle());
});
```

Also, be sure your *#text div* has a height, `#text{ height: 50px; }` for example.